# How do I containerize a large Sql Server database with multiple users?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I am attempting to get Docker to work.  I picked one of our apps and was able to get it containerized and running, but I'm struggling to get it to connect to the DB now.

The way our code is structured is that we have a large shared code solution that contains over 100 different projects.  We use those projects largely as our DataSource so each project has it's own user/pass in to a single database.  These all build out to DLL's that we then reference from our different web apps.

We have a single connectionString file for each environment (dev, stage, etc) and in our web.config we can swap out the path to those files to run our apps against the different environments.  The connection strings in a given file connect to the same server, but with different credentials.

Since I'm still just trying to do a local proof of concept before attempting to roll this out across more of our ecosystem, is there a quick and dirty way to set this up in my Docker-Compose.yml?

I'm using Docker for Windows inside Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes?

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dir c:\ProgramData\docker\volumes
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is B835-2811

 Directory of c:\ProgramData\docker\volumes

02/06/2018  03:46 PM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2018  03:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/06/2018  03:46 PM            32,768 metadata.db
02/06/2018  03:38 PM                 0 metadata.db.lock
               2 File(s)         32,768 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  84,093,935,616 bytes free

C:\Users\Administrator>docker volume create --name testvol
testvol

C:\Users\Administrator>dir c:\ProgramData\docker\volumes
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is B835-2811

 Directory of c:\ProgramData\docker\volumes

02/06/2018  03:49 PM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2018  03:49 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/06/2018  03:49 PM            32,768 metadata.db
02/06/2018  03:38 PM                 0 metadata.db.lock
02/06/2018  03:49 PM    <DIR>          testvol
               2 File(s)         32,768 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  84,072,288,256 bytes free


C:\Users\Administrator>docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:46:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:55:16 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: I keep seeing volumes coming up, but either I'm not putting A and B together, or I'm over-complicating it in my own mind.  At this point, I just want to get my app inside a container and connecting to the db server.  I'm not seeing how a volume ties to my server.